# Writing and reading binary files structure/classes with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, binaryfiles, fstream

I'm learning to work with binary files. While experimenting with files, I discovered something that I can't figure out. I added the description of the problem in the code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class C
{
public:
    C() {};
    C(string title) : title(title) {};
    string title;
};

class A
{
public:
    A() {};
    A(string& title, C *c2) : title(title), c2(c2)
    {
        c = new C{ title };
    }
    int a = 10;
    string title;
    C* c = nullptr;
    C* c2 = nullptr;
};

class B
{
public:
    vector<A*>* vec = new vector<A*>{};
};

//function that writes class B to binary file
void serialize(B& b)
{
    std::ofstream ofs("test.bin", std::fstream::binary);
    if (!ofs.is_open())
    {
        return;
    }

    ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&b), sizeof(B));
    ofs.close();
}

//function that "reads class B" from binary files
void deserialize(B& b)
{
    std::ifstream ifs("test.bin", std::fstream::binary);
    if (!ifs.is_open())
    {
        return;
    }
    if (!(ifs.peek() == std::ifstream::traits_type::eof()))
        ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&b), sizeof(B));

    ifs.close();
}

int main()
{

    B* b = new B{}; //creating instance of B
    string s1{ "QWE" }; //some random strings
    string s2{ "CC" }; //some random strings
    A* a = new A{ s1, new C{s2} }; //creating instance of A
    
    //Adding a instance to the b's vector
    b->vec->push_back(a); 
    b->vec->push_back(new A{ s1 , new C{s2} });
    b->vec->push_back(new A{ s1 , new C{s2} });
    b->vec->push_back(new A{ s1 , new C{s2} });

    //Writing to binary file
    serialize(*b);

    
    delete a; //release a
    B b2;

    // Problem. If i read from binary file, the fisrt instance of A
    // which was deleted is not exists, when other elements -- exist
    // How does it works?
    deserialize(*b); 
    deserialize(b2);

    return 0;
}
```

If i will not release **a** than everything works fine. **b** and **b2** after reading the binary file contains all elements. But if i'll release **a** after writing **b** and **b2** will not contain a. Why **b** and **b2** doesn't contain **a** if i released it after writing to file?

Comment: Pointers don't copy very well to files.  The Operating System may reload your code in a different place than when the pointers were written to the files.  The pointers in the file may point to another task's memory or not be valid at all.  The best method is to write the length and data that the pointer points to.  Don't write pointers to a file.

Comment: Let's take text as an example.  Text is a variable length field, so block writing doesn't work.  A preferred method is to write the length of the string first, followed by the text.  This allows for the text I/O to be performed in block.  For example when reading, you can read the quantity first, then allocate that memory, then block read the text.  A lot more efficient than reading character by character searching for a termination character.

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ serialization" for more information.

Comment: @OP Hate to throw cold water on you, but none of this code will work.  You need to start over from scratch, and actually properly serialize the data.  You cannot simply write pointers to a file, and you certainly cannot write non-trivially-copyable types such as `B` to a file as raw bytes.

Comment: @OP -- First, you have to determine what the binary file consist of in terms of *data*, not classes or pointers.  The goal is to write the *data* to the file in a way such that when you read the *data* back, you take the data and reconstruct the object from that data.  For example, you don't write the vector object to a file -- you write the data that the vector represents to a file.

Comment: @OP In addition, if you took a look at your code carefully, you are using `sizeof(B)` as the parameter in the file reading and writing.  If that vector contained 1000 elements, the `sizeof(B)` isn't going to magically change to 1000 (or higher).  The `sizeof` tells you the *compile-time* size of class `B`.  So right there, you see that the functions could never work correctly.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thank you for your help. I'm going to check `serialization`.
@PaulMcKenzie Thank you. I'll think about `data representing`